# Method giving incorrect "setter"

Tags: objective-c, methods, setter

I have the class Player

```
@interface Player : NSObject{...}
-(int) setAttack:(int)MonsterNumber;
Player.m
-(int) setAttack:(int)MonsterNumber{...
return damage;
}
```

However, when I run this program I get the error "Player.h:28:1: error: type of setter must be void [3]" I get this error 3 times.

Thank you for the help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cocoa pattern is that setters return (void) always.   You really don't want to do otherwise.   Define a `damage` getter or @property.  Or rename the method to something descriptive of what it does:

```
- (int) damageForAttack:(int)attack;
```

I was surprised the compiler warned about it.  I wasn't able to reproduce the warning.